# Weird syntax of an EnumMap

Tags: java, enums

An EnumMap is defined as follow:

```
Class EnumMap<K extends Enum<K>,V>
```

What does "K extends Enum<K>" really mean?

I can understand this for example:

```
K extends Number
```

In this case K is any type of object that extend Number. For example Integer.

But what does `K extends Enum<K>` mean?

Answer (score 2):

`K extends Enum<K>` introduces a type parameter `K` that can only bind to sub-types of an `Enum` whose first-type parameter is itself.

Comment: the only answer which tries to translate the Java to natural English, which was the question.  A longer answer would be more informative.

Answer (score 1):

It's **self referential**, and the same thing is repeated on java.lang.Enum - it's to ensure the genericised methods cast correctly, see the definition of [java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Class, String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29).

A good (if long) example of similar usage is [this article](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/emcmanus/archive/2010/10/25/using-builder-pattern-subclasses) defining an AbstractBuilder.

Another [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2008/06/12/generics-the-knee-bone-s-connected-to-the-toe-bone-pattern.aspx?Redirected=true) to self referential generics (examples in C#, but point is the same)

Answer (score 1):

The Enum class is defined as:

```
class Enum<E extends Enum<E>>
```

It means that the generic type is a class that is itself and is an Enum. It's just the way it's expressed in java syntax.

There are plenty of similar examples in the JDK, like

```
<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The superclass of all enum types is `Enum<K>`, the generic argument being the type of `Enum<K>`. Essentially, this is being used to ensure that `K` is an enum type.